# Mysql Where Column A = X and Column B = Y and or Column B = Z

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database, rdbms

I'm trying to get a set of values from a pivot table where column A is equal to an array of values, so for example ID 12 has attribute_value_id equal to 3 and 9. Can this be done? I've got this far...

```
ID | post_id | attribute_id | attribute_value_id
8      12          1             3
9      12          2            13
10     13          1             3
11     13          2             9
12     16          1             3
13     16          2             9
88     11          1             1
89     11          2             8
90     11          3            18
91     11          4            22
```

The query...

```
select * 
from `searching_for_posts` 
where (
    select count(*) 
    from `attributes` 
    inner join `searching_for_attributes`
    on `attributes`.`id` = `searching_for_attributes`.`attribute_id` 
    where `searching_for_attributes`.`searching_for_post_id` = `searching_for_posts`.`id` 
    and (`attribute_value_id` = 3 and `attribute_value_id` = 9)
) >= 1
```

If I use the `and` then I get no values. If I use the `or` then I get 3 values but it should return 2. I have limited SQL experience.

Comment: `(\`attribute_value_id\` = 3 and \`attribute_value_id\` = 9)` is logically impossible.... `attribute_value_id` cannot have both `3` and `9` as its value at the same time, don't you mean perhaps `(\`attribute_value_id\` = 3 OR \`attribute_value_id\` = 9)`.... or perhaps you mean `(\`attribute_value_id\` IN (3, 9)`

Comment: @MarkBaker No, what i'd like is to get data like so, if someone searches for a product and they want all products that have are blue and have a in-built CD player. All attribute data is in a pivot table and each item has its own row. This may be a problem. Let me know if thats clear enough.

Comment: 1. Look at your data. There is only one row with ID 12. Typo? 2. What table is this? What is data for the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`.  Your logic is hard to follow, but it is something like this:

```
select post_id
from table t
where attribute_value_id in (3, 9)
group by post_id
having count(distinct attribute_id) = 2;
```

I would think you would want to check on `attribute_id` as well, but that doesn't seem to be part of the question.

EDIT:

If these are stored in another table:

```
select a.post_id
from attributes a join
     searching_for_attributes sfa
     on a.attribute_id = sfa.attribute_id and
        a.attribute_value_id = sfa.attribute_value_id
group by a.post_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from searching_for_attributes);
```

Comment: Thanks for you in depth response. I've taken inspiration from your first response using the GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT methods. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @GordonLinoff answer, I've managed to use GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT to get the desired data. Here's what I came up with and hope this helps someone else...

```
select * 
from `searching_for_posts`
where (
    select count(*) 
    from `attributes` 
    inner join `searching_for_attributes` on `attributes`.`id` = `searching_for_attributes`.`attribute_id` 
    where `searching_for_attributes`.`searching_for_post_id` = `searching_for_posts`.`id` 
    and `attribute_value_id` in (3, 9)
    having count(distinct `attributes`.`id`) = 2
) >= 1
group by `id`
```